# I don't find the error

Tags: c

I can't find the mistake on the do-while. The loop keeps going if I answer 'N' to the question.(The app is for finding the average of height of an uncertain number of people).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i;
    float measure[i],sum,average;
    char sex;
    char yn;


    do{
        for(i=1;i;i++) { 
            printf("Persoa %d",i);
            printf("\nIndique se é home (H) ou muller (M): ");

            scanf("%s",&sex);
                while((sex != 'M') && (sex != 'H'))
                {
                    printf("Lo ha escrito mal.");
                    printf("\nIndique se é home (H) ou muller (M): ");
                    scanf("%s",&sex);        
                }

            printf("Indique a súa measure (en metros): ");
            scanf("%f",&measure[i]);

            sum=sum+measure[i];

            printf("\nDesea seguir? (Y/N): ");
            scanf("%s",&yn);
                while((yn != 'Y') && (yn != 'N'))
                {
                    printf("Lo ha escrito mal.");
                    printf("\nDesea seguir? (Y/N): ");
                    scanf("%s",&yn);
                }
        }
    }while(yn == 'Y');

    average=sum/i;
    printf("\nA media de measures é: %f m.",average);    

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Need help guys. I need to send this to my teacher tomorrow. I'm a noob on this language :(

Comment: This looks like C/C++, not C#.

Comment: What is the `for` for? You have just one loop, so you can track of the `i` variable yourself, without a `for` that trips you up.

Comment: The scanf() call corrupts the stack, anything is possible.  The yn variable is %c, not %s

Comment: @QuercuzHacheDe Do you understand how for() loops work, and what a `break` statement would do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this correction to your program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */
#define NB_MESURES  50

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i=0;
    float measure[NB_MESURES] /* NB_MESURES is predefined to be 50*/
   ,sum=0,average=0;
    char sex=0;
    char yn=0;


    while(1){ /*endless loop (1)*/

            printf("Persoa %d",i);
            printf("\nIndique se é home (H) ou muller (M): ");


            while(1) /*endless loop (level 2)*/
            {
                scanf(" %c",&sex);
                if((sex == 'M') || (sex == 'H')) break; /*Upper case*/
                if((sex == 'm') || (sex == 'h')) break; /*Lower case*/

                /* ok exit loop (level 2)
                   else show the help message */
                printf("Lo ha escrito mal.");
                printf("\nIndique se é home (H) ou muller (M): ");  
            }

            printf("Indique a súa measure (en metros): ");
            scanf("%f",&measure[i]);

            sum=sum+measure[i];
            i++; 
            if(i==NB_MESURES){
                  /* 
                    we can not add more than 50 elements
                    exiting loop (1)
                  */
                printf("\nMax Allowed entries is %d\n",NB_MESURES);
                break;
            }else{
                printf("\nDesea seguir? (Y/N): ");
                while(1) /* loop (level 2) */
                {
                    scanf(" %c",&yn);
                    if((yn == 'Y') || (yn == 'N')) break;
                    if((yn == 'y') || (yn == 'n')) break; 
                    /* if the input was different than ['Y','y','N','n']
                       show newt message else we break and use yn in the next check to exit loop (level 1)
                    */
                    printf("Lo ha escrito mal.");
                    printf("\nDesea seguir? (Y/N): "); 
                }

                if((yn == 'N') || (yn == 'n')) break; /*Exit level 1*/
            }
    }

    average=sum/i;
    printf("\nA media de measures é: %f m.\n",average);    

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: The answer would benefit from providing more explanation.

Comment: i added some comments

Answer (score 1):

two main errors are:
the most critical is:

```
float measure[i];
```

you have to declare exactly the size of the table eg:

```
float measure[50];
```

the second is: scanf string format for char is `"%c"` not `"%s"`

still other error exists.